# Apache running as root instead of user specified in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions, wordpress

I'm trying to enable WordPress to upload files to the wp-content folder without setting permissions for the folder to 777. However, I'm having some difficulties.

The group and user set for the wp-content folder match the group and user Apache is configured to be using in httpd.conf. However, when I run the below command, it appears that Apache is actually running as root rather than the user specified in httpd.conf.

**httpd.conf Configuration**

```
User xxx
Group yyy
```

**Command Run to Determine User Apache is Running As**

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

**Output from the above command**

```
513       1294  0.4  1.4 316420 54864 ?        S    08:30   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

513 is the correct UID for user xxx, so that appears correctly. However, I'm still not able to upload files within WordPress without setting permissions for the wp-content folder to 777.

Can somebody tell me what the issue is here?

Comment: You're running the check as root and it's showing the command "grep apache" as the process root is running!
Try `ps -ef | grep apache` instead.

Comment: Bah...too early in the morning for stupid mistakes like that. So the user it is running as it "apache" listed at the end?

Comment: First column is user.

Comment: So what am I missing here? If httpd.conf specifies apache should run as xxx, why don't I see that when I run this?

Comment: What you're missing is that apache is not running at all. As mentioned by Colin, the process you're seeing is the grep command you're just executing.

Comment: Sorry, I see what I've done now. Going to update the question to ask things more accurately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache always needs to start as root, then it uses setuid to switch to user context of specified user in httpd.conf.

Without root (uid = 0) you can not create listening socket on privileged ports (below 1024)

For details read this documents:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html

**From first link:**

```
# ps -ef | grep -i http | awk '{print $1}'
root
apache
apache
apache
apache
apache
```

Comment: So am I supposed to let it run as root and then change it on a per site basis to a different user rather than universally? It doesn't really seem secure to let httpd run as root.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin : see my updated answer

Comment: Having read through the link, I've already got this setup correctly. However, I still can't upload to wp-content from WP even with the permissions set to 755. If WP (and httpd) are running as UID 513, as it says it is, shouldn't it be able to upload files without issue?

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin which users is the owner for the wp-content/ directory?  It should be the apache user (513 in your case).  <code>chown -R 513 wp-content/ </code> should do it for you.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin please post ls -ld wp-content

Comment: <pre>ls -l wp-content</pre> shows that the user and group are set to the same as what the httpd user uses...the only difference is that is shows the actual user name here instead of the UID (513).

Comment: ls -ld wp-content output: drwxr-xr-x 9 xxx yyy 4096

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin : is xxx equals to 513/httpd?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, but I just figured out what is going on. The initial permissions are fine but for some reason, WP is changing the permissions of files after they are uploaded (to 533) so files can't be overwritten with the new permissions. I'm not sure why it is doing that, but it is a different question. I'll award the answer to you though as it would have solved things had this been the true issue.